# R cannot find my coordinates when I use the function kde3d

Tags: r, coordinates, kernel-density, ternary

I'm trying to do a 3d kernel density estimation on a ternary plot using the function kde3d, but when I run the code, it can't find my second coordinate.

I'm using the function

> kde3d(C, S, R, 0.588, n = 41, lims = c(range(C), range(S), range(R)))

but when I run the code it gives me the error message:

> Error: object 'S' not found

C, S, and R are the names of columns in my dataframe. I've switched the orders of the coordinates, tried a, b, and c (the names of columns C, S, and R before I renamed them), and tried x, y, and z. Why can R find my first coordinate but not my second

Comment: You have to tell R that these variables are columns in your data frame. You could have several data frames with the same column names, so it is not reasonable to expect R to know where to look for them. If your data frame is called `df` then you can do `with(df, kde3d(C, S, R, 0.588, n = 41, lims = c(range(C), range(S), range(R))))`. Alternatively, specify each one: `kde3d(df$C, df$S, df$R, 0.588, n = 41, lims = c(range(df$C), range(df$S), range(df$R)))`. There is already an object called `C` in your search path (it's a function in the `stats` package), which is why it is `S` that is not found